# Can not press enter key with textarea in imacros

Tags: imacros

I just tried to hit the enter key with imacros in firefox but doesnt work.
The photo of my div is:

[The image of my div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ARVl.jpg)

I tried using the following code:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>#number>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>textarea" KEY=13
```

But not work why is not working keypress with imacros.
my version is:
8.9.7

Comment: no one can explain why is not pressing?

Comment: with kantu it's possible to read txt files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes other key event types might help:

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYDOWN SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>#number>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>textarea" KEY=13
```

or

```
EVENT TYPE=KEYUP SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>#number>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>textarea" KEY=13
```

Comment: i tried with at the last DIV:nth-of-type(1)>textarea because its first one span and after one div . the text dissapear but never it's showed in my input. so i will try with kantu.

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by a wrong selector... Good luck anyway.

Comment: can you help me with the other post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815884/check-if-text-string-exist-on-my-webpage-using-imacros and thx for the help!